# Why to place an email as image or replacing "name@email.com" with "name at email dot com"

Tags: internet

I noticed it in, for example, the profiles of some Stack Exchange users. So I wonder: did they want to protect themselves from spamming bots this way, or ...?

Does it have to do with security? Because I guess that the bots can easily convert something like "name at email dot com" to "name@email.com"...

> [image]

...or read simple images?

> [image]

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45041/is-using-dot-and-at-in-email-addresses-in-public-text-still-useful (does not discuss images)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not to be the perfect security, just make spamming harder.

Spammers will have to scrap lots and lots of pages to create a database of email addresses. It's cheaper to get the text, search for a pattern like `name@email.com` and add to the database than to search for `name at server.com`, or `name at server dot com`, or `name at server . com`, and other variations, parse all, validate all and add to the database.

So the point is to not be the lower hanging fruit. You could use a javascript that needs to solve a captcha, an equation, then asks for clicking on a happy cat to show the email, but if a spammer really wants your email, he will create a bot (or use Amazon Mechanical Turk) to "solve" your riddles.